# I gave all my Youtube cookies to somebody. Can this person hack my Google / Youtube account?

Tags: google-chrome, security, cookies, youtube, session-cookies

I went to my developer tools, I copy / paste all my youtube.com cookies and I gave it to somebody.
Can this person use it to be connected to my Youtube / Gmail account ??
(Cookies I gave are HSID, LOGIN_INFO, __secure-PSAID, etc...)

I am afraid about that !
Thank you

Comment: This is a programming Q/A site and this question is not about programming.

Comment: I had to give those information cause I work as a web developer. I think an answer to this question could be helpful regarding programming stuff (I work on Youtube API) and interesting for web developers ! There's a "security" tag on stackoverflow, I think my question is related to this and that this bring cookie / security knowledge to the community

Comment: I can understand that, but IT is a large landscape, and there are e.g. sites such as [security.se] that deal with this. However, as it stood I am afraid that there should be quite a lot of dupes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible to use your cookies to connect to your account without your password before you closed your session. After the old cookies will be useless.

https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_hijacking_attack
See last part of this article (Prevention): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

- You should activate the Multi Factor Authentication, if google see your are connecting to another location it will ask you to valide with the MFA your connection.
- You have also the possibility to view from where and when you were connected to your account with google, I don't remember where is it but it's on the google setting (after you connect on it).

I answer you in general I don't kwon how google manages their cookie

Comment: 1/ Yes, actually I think Google could see if the user-agent is different if someone would use my cookies, and Google could give me a notification on my phone / by mail.
2/ I have 2FA protection
3/ I changed my password but I think this does'nt change anything..
4/ Thank you for the answer